# Problems about Consistency model in google file system

Tags: distributed-system, gfs

After reading the article [The Google File System](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf), I'm still confused with some points:

1. what are the advantages of 'append operation' versus 'write operation'?The article emphasize using append operation rather than write operation,i wonder why.Append is faster than write?
2. To maintain consitency between redundancies of a chunk, gfs use lease to let a chunkserver as a primary, and let the primary decides the operation sequence to achieve consistency,my problem is if after retrying, the update operation still can't succeed,the redundancies will be in inconsistent state.Then when different clients come to read the same chunk at same offset that was updated failed, they may read differnt content.How does gfs deal with this kind of problem.
3. If errors occurs in appending operation,will the primary chunkserver choose a new offset to append the record? What does a record mean?when client read a file, how can it deal with some padding or duplicated records in the file?

Comment: Please correct link to the article. Did you mean [this paper](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

All of your questions are directly addressed in the paper, so you should read it again more carefully. But I will give short answers to each part of the question to give you an entry:

1. This preservers consistency while enabling concurrent writes. If you modify existing data, concurrent writes on the existing data mess up consistency. If you do appends only, you can reorder them at will maintaining the consistency model defined by GFS.
2. It does not deal with that, as its part of the consistency model. The clients must handle it.
3. I do not understand this part of the question.

Regards, Christian